# PayPal Dynamic Pricing and IPN?

Tags: html, paypal

So, I am trying to make a buy now page where I can change the price. So I got a buy now PayPal Button.

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@example.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Dildo">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="12.99">
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif"         border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it\'s fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

But when I use this, it isn't sending to the IPN. My IPN works fine as i've tested it. I just can't seem to get PayPal to send to the IPN when a payment is made with a button like this. But I need to change the price dynamically.

Comment: Can you also post the code of a button for which an IPN generates normally? It might help in determining what is different between them.

Comment: have you saved the `notify_url` in your profile? else you have to include it as field.

Comment: Yes, i've set the IPN. The IPN works fine when I use a premade paypal button just not when I try and make a value on its own. I was wondering if I made a premade button with no price or anything then put the amount input in, would that work

Comment: IPN works regardless of the type of integration - if IPN is enabled in your Profile, then it *will* generate and send a HTTP POST for all transaction-related events occurring within the account. You should be able to see all generated IPN messages under 'History' > 'IPN History' within the PayPal account if you've enabled IPN within the account. What's the status of them?